# Set a variable value in one class, which is returned by a method in another

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, return

So i have 2 classes. The first one reads information from a file and stores it in a 2D array and then returns it. Like so:

```
public class Skaitymas{
File f = new File("Events.txt");
private int lines = 0;
private Scanner sc;
private String[][] myArray;

public void skaityti() throws IOException{ 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Events.txt"));
    try{
        while (reader.readLine() != null){
            lines++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
} 

public String[][] iMasyva() throws IOException{ 
    sc = new Scanner(new File("Events.txt"));
    String linija = null;
    int counter = 0;
    myArray = new String[lines][5];
    for(int i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        linija = sc.nextLine().toString();
        String[] dabartinesLinijosStringai = linija.split(" ");
        for(int j = 0; j<myArray[0].length; j++){
             myArray[counter][j] = dabartinesLinijosStringai[j];
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return myArray;   //The 2D array i wish to return
}
}
```

On my other class i wish to initialize a new 2D array, which gets the returned 2D array from the 1st Class. I create an object of the 1st class and then initialize the method, which returns the value. Like so:

```
Skaitymas read = new Skaitymas();

String[][] mas = read.iMasyva();
```

But i get this error: Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

I dont even know if im supposed to do it like this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a stack-trace or something because It works for me.

Comment: Ok your method in your second class also needs to throw an IOException otherwise you'll get this error. You should probably not be using a method throw and use a try-catch instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you catch the IOException instead of throwing it in class "Skaitymas" constructor

```
try{
        while (reader.readLine() != null){
            lines++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }catch(IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: yup this ^ just what i said in my comment